# ACF Clone Field - Set Default Value

Tags: wordpress, clone, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up an ACF Clone Field called 'NJ' in Field Group 'NJ', which clones all of the 70+ ACF fields in Field Group 'Global'. These field groups appear on the same custom post type.

I would like for these cloned fields to have a default/fallback value set, which is equal to the value in the original field. So that if the cloned field is left blank, it will default to the value in the original field. Which will in turn, remove the need for lots of conditional statements in my template code.

**Example:**

- 'Global' Field Group > Number Field: 'Total Games' > Value: '100'
- 'NJ' Field Group > Number Field (created by Clone Field): 'Total
  Games' > (if no value is input, use value from Global Field Group on
  the same post)

I found a couple of answers on here that copy the values when post is saved, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. It may not be possible I know but any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us so we will be able to help. Without specific knowledge of the ACF clone field, we don't know what you are trying to do, so we can't help you fix code we cannot see :) If you update your question with the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and details of what you have tried (so we don't suggest the same), we might be able to help.

Comment: Alternatively, if this isn't a simple code fix, you might not get the expertise you need here as this is a general programming site, so you'd probably get better help in the ACF plugin support on wordpress.org (or ACF themselves if you have the Pro version)

Comment: Sorry about that. I've posted in the WordPress stackexchange now. Thanks for the kind welcome and advice :)

Comment: I'd also suggest asking in the [Support page for ACF on wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). They've helped me out there before. You'll get experts in ACF there, and even if the plugin developer doesn't respond other users might be able to help. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

So providing you have one clone subfield in **NJ** acf group field, which clones all 70+ of your selected **Global** subfields, and if you dumped all fields like so...

`echo '<pre>'; print_r(get_fields()); echo '</pre>'; exit;`

Which returns something like this...

```
Array
(
    [global] => Array
        (
            [total_games] => 24
            ...
        )

    [nj] => Array
        (
            [total_games] => 
            ...
        )

    ... 
)
```

If your returned array structure matches mine then you could add the below code into your functions to simply loop through all your **NJ** cloned subfields, check if the current value is blank, then check if **Global** has a matching key, if has matching key, get the **Global** value and assign it to the corresponding **NJ** cloned field.

When the loop has finished, then update the **NJ** field as one big array when saving/updating the post (custom post type). Thus returning the expected result in your post.

In my code I am checking the post type for `post`. Change `post` to your custom post type and this should work.

See comments in code below...

```
// acf action that runs when you save post
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'nj_empty_clone_value_check', 20 );

/**
 * @param $post_id int
 * @return void
 */
function nj_empty_clone_value_check($post_id) {

    // global post
    global $post;

    // check we are on the correct post type (currently set to post)
    if($post->post_type <> 'post') return;

    // get all the fields values from our current post
    $fields = get_fields($post_id);

    // changes check
    $changes = false;

    // for each of the cloned subfields in NJ group
    foreach ($fields['nj'] as $key => $value) {

        // if current NJ group cloned subfield value is blank
        if(!$value) {

            // check the original Global group subfield value is not blank
            if(!empty($fields['global'][$key])) {

                // update the NJ group subfield value with the Global group subfield value
                $fields['nj'][$key] = $fields['global'][$key];

                // update changes check to true
                $changes = true;

            }

        }

    }

    // if any changes have been made to NJ group
    if($changes) {

        // update NJ group field with updated NJ array data
        update_field('nj', $fields['nj'], $post_id);

    }

}
```